# Difference in Regular Expressions (Regex)

Tags: regex

What is the difference between the following regexes?

1. `/[0-9]/` matches Numbers, correct?
2. `/[a-z]/` matches lower case letters, correct?
3. `/[A-Z]/` matches upper case letters, correct?
4. `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/` matches?
5. `/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,:,;]/` matches only those special chars, correct

So how do #4 & #5 differ?

Comment: Did you mean /[A-Z]/ for example 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `/[0-9]/` matches one digit
2. `/[a-z]/` matches one lowercase letter
3. `/[A-Z]/` matches one uppercase letter
4. `/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/` matches any one character other than letter (lowercase/uppercase) or digit
5. `/.[!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,?,_,~,:,;]/` matches any one character `.` followed by any one character listed between `[` and `]` *(comma is also one of them and you don't have to list it multiple times, it is not separator)*
6. `/[!,@#$%^&*?_~:;]/` matches any one character listed between `[` and `]`

Answer (score 0):

3 matches lowercase letters, [A-Z] matches caps. 
4 could be rewritten as [a-Z0-9]
5 contains a . in front of its character group which which matches any single character.

None of those expressions contain start or end anchors, so those all mean if the string CONTAINS something in that group.

Answer (score 0):

4 will match any character that is not alphanumeric.

5 will match any character (the leading period) followed by any of the characters in the brackets, which do *not* have to be separated by commas (you're in essence saying over and over that you can match a comma)

They are not the same, and the "not alphanumeric" case is more comprehensive - for example, it will match a parenthesis `(` or a caret `^`, which you didn't include in the options for number 5